# How to get Vim Latex-suite projects (with .latexmain-files) to configure spelling in subfiles correctly

Tags: vim, spelling, vim-latex

I use Latex in larger projects and I use the following file structure:

```
project/
  mainfile.tex
  mainfile.tex.latexmain
  tex/
    subfile1.tex
    subfile2.tex
    ...
```

The command `\input{tex/subfileN.tex}` is used to import the content from each file in the `tex/` folder.
The `mainfile.tex.latexmain` work as expected and cross-reference completion across the project is available.

However, spite recogized correctly, spelling in each of the subfiles does not work properly. Spelling in comments follow `g:tex_comment_nospell` and verbatim follow `g:tex_verbspell`, but nothing in the document itself irrespectively of the state of`g:tex_nospell`.

A little bit of exploring and I found at that by adding a `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}`-pair, the document behaves normal again. I'm assuming that latex-suite thinks that the document is *stand-alone* and I'm actually writing a preamble. But the preamble and `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}`-pair can be found in `mainfile.tex`.

To enable spelling in such projects I in practice either comment out each line or add a `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}`-pair. Neither are very good solution to the problem.

Is there a good way to get around this? Alternatively, is there another way of structuring my documents I should be using that doesn't involve me editing a file with 8000 lines?

Answer (score 1):

One solution, though not very satisfying, is to turn off spelling through

```
let g:tex_nospell=1
```

and instead let spelling be handled through an module like Syntastic: http://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic.